# Get roles from reaction

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, roles

I am trying to create a message with reactions for my bot, if a user clicks on a specific reaction he is automatically given a role chosen by me via code. I don't understand where the problem is in what I've done.

````
        await msg.react('');
          if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            if (reaction.message.channel.id === "793239655331004448");
            let role = reaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '689880327782400203');
            member.roles.add(role.id);
            console.log('Ruolo Aggiunto'); //role added
          } else {
            console.log("Errore"); //Error
          }```
````

Answer (score 0):

````
await msg.react('');
          if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
            if (reaction.message.channel.id === "793239655331004448");
            console.log('lol');
            let role = reaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === '689880327782400203');
            console.log('lol');
            member.roles.add(role);
            console.log('Ruolo Aggiunto'); //role added
          } else {
            console.log("Errore"); //Error
          }```
````